# Handling PermGen errors in ant bpelc task

Tags: ant, bpel

I've been hitting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen error when compiling a project with ant under Linux with jdk 1.5.0_11. the same project compiles under windows without problem.

Usually this relates to the MaxPermSize allocated to the JVM. Irakli Nadareishvili has one of the [best explanations of PermGen errors](http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) and guide to setting [Java HotSpot VMOptions](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp#PerformanceTuning) (e.g. -XX:MaxPermSize=128M)

In this case, I quickly narrowed the issue down to a particular [bpelc](http://ode.apache.org/bpelc-task.html) ant task

```
<bpelc input="${build.dir}/bpel/bpel.xml" 
out="${build.dir}/output" rev="${version}" home="${bpel.home}"/>
```

Now I don't think bpelc takes the compilerarg element like javac:

```
  <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
         destdir="${classes.dir}"
         classpathref="libraries">
    <compilerarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=128M"/>
  </javac>
```

So how to fix the error for the bpelc task? The best solution I've come up with so far is to set the [ANT_OPTS](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars) environment variable. This seems to have avoided the problem to date.

```
export ANT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Can anyone shed more light? Is that a sure-fire fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `bpelc` task executes inside the original JVM running ant, then setting `ANT_OPTS` (or something equivalent) is the only possible solution.

One such equivalent thing might be to refactor that task to a second ant build file and run that using a separate JVM. Not really nicer, but depending on your environment it might be easier to implement.

Comment: @saua thanks for the reinforcement! If we hit the PermGen problem again I think your suggestion of refactoring will be the next step.